# Confusion with "..." operator in golang

Tags: arrays, go, operators, slice

What is the difference between the following two syntaxes in go?

```
x := [...]int{ 1:1, 2:2 }
x := []int{ 1:1, 2:2 }
```

Go's document says "The notation ... specifies an array length equal to the maximum element index plus one". But both the above syntaxes gives same lenght (3).

Is there a name for this operator "..."?
Didn't find a way to search this operator in google.

Comment: You might want to work your way through tour.golang.org .

Answer (score 16):

The first line creates an [**array**](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) using an *array literal*, its length computed automatically by the compiler. It is detailed in the [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) section of the Language Specification.

> The notation ... specifies an array length equal to the maximum element index plus one.

<sup>Note: this is not to be confused with the `...` used to specify *variadic* parameters or to pass slices as their values. It is detailed in the [Function types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) section of the spec.</sup>

The second line uses a *slice literal* and will result in a [**slice**](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). Note that under the hood an array will also be created, but that is opaque.

Comment: I have a doubt. First one creates an array [0, 1, 2] and the second one creates a slice(lenght = capacity = 3) refering the array [0, 1, 2]. What is the difference of having these two

Comment: The slice is a kind of dynamic array, while the size of the array is fixed.

Comment: @Spartan Well, for a start, they are 2 different types. If you're asking about the usefulness/usage of arrays and slices, read the Effective Go: [Arrays](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays), [Slices](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices), or the Blog articles [Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) and [Arrays, Slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: @Spartan To supplement on differences: arrays are _values_, slices are _references_. You are encouraged to pass slices (because they are just references) and they refer to the same underlying array. Arrays should be passed as values with care because that passes a copy of the array. Arrays are useful to when planning the detailed layout of memory and sometimes can help avoid allocation, but primarily they are a building block for slices.